# Is there a way to determine in which subset a value belongs to?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not looking for a specific solution but more reading material on how to solve this type of question (Eventually I'm hoping to derive/find a process to calculate this independent of its variation). I have a problem that contains several sections that are variations of the problem described bellow. For completeness I've added one of the variations at the end.

**English description of the process**

For each step I take a set of integers and split them up into two sets `even index's` and `odd index's` and append one of these to the set `A` and keep the next as the input for the next step. In each step I alternate which set I choose to append to the set `A`.

Now given a specific integer how can you determine in which set of `A` it belongs to

**A more mathematical description of the process**

Let `N` be a set of positive integers `{1,2,3,4,5,6,...}` defined by `n = x`

Let `S` be a set and let function `f(S) = F` return a subset of the set `S` and function `g(S) = G` return a subset of `S`.

`f(x) = 2x + 1` and `g(x) = 2x + 0`

Let union of `F` and `G` be the set `S` and the intersection of `F` and `G` be the empty set `{}`.

Let `A` be a set of sets. let `a_i` be the ith set of `A`.

Let `T` be a set of subsets. Let `R_i` be an element in `T`

Let `R_i` be a subset of `N`. Where the union of sets `a_x` where `x<i` and `R_i` is set the set `N` and again the intersection of those sets is the empty set `{}`.

`a_0 = f(N)` and `R_0 = g(N)`

`a_1 = g(R_0)` and `R_1 = f(R_0)` which can be rewritten as `a_1 = g(g(N))` and `R_1 = f(g(N))`

`a_2 = f(R_1)` and `R_2 = g(R_1)` which can be rewritten as `a_2 = f(f(g(N))` and `R_1 = g(f(g(N)))`

`T = [g(N), f(R_0), g(R_1), f(R_2), g(R_3), f(R_4),...]`

`A = [f(N), g(R_0), f(R_1), g(R_2), f(R_3), g(R_4),...]`

or rewritten as

`T = [g(N), f(g(N)), g(f(g(N)), f(g(f(g(N))),...]`

`A = [f(N), g(g(N)), f(f(g(N)), g(g(f(g(N))),...]`

or rewritten in terms of their generating function

`T = [[2x], [4x+2], [8x+2], [16x+10],...]`

`A = [[2x+1], [4x], [8x+6], [16x+2],...]`

**Question**

Given `v` what is the value of `i` (index) for the set `a_i` where `v` is an element in `a_i`?

**Helpful References**

Since the generating function of `a_i` is of the form `y = mx+b`

`m = 2^(i+1)` and `b` = Conjecture [A176965 : a(n) = 2^(n-1) - (2^n*(-1)^n + 2)/3.](https://oeis.org/A176965)

Also since the generating function of `R_i` is of the form `z = wx+u`

`w = 2^(i+1)` and `u` = Conjecture [A263053 : Number of (n+1) X (1+1) 0..1 arrays with each row and column not divisible by 3, read as a binary number with top and left being the most significant bits.](https://oeis.org/A263053) offset with a starting `0` : `[0, 2, 2, 10, 10, 42, 42, 170,...]`

Note: If you were to include `N` as the first element in `T` (shifting all `R_i` => `R_i+1`) the sequence of values for `u` starts with `[0,0,2,2,10,10,...]` which keeps the pattern.

**Variation**

I only alternate every 3 steps.

`T = [g(N), f(R_0), f(R_1), f(R_2), g(R_3), g(R_4),...]`

`A = [f(N), g(R_0), g(R_1), g(R_2), f(R_3), f(R_4),...]`

Comment: Looks like $A$ and $T$ are sequences of sets, not sets of sets.

Comment: Write v in binary. Compare this to the sequence of bits ...1010101010. The right-most bit where they differ gives you the index you are looking for. For example 18 is 10010 in binary, and differs from 01010 in the fourth bit from the right, so will be in the fourth set, [16x+2]. Note that this this set contains all numbers with a binary representation ending in 0010.